# How do I use LATERAL VIEW in this situation with multiple tables join in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have this table

```
table 1
id, array<string>(place_id)
1, [1 ,2]
2, [2, 3]

table 2 (Metadata)
id, some_meta

table 3 (Places)
1, Name1
2, Name2
3, Name3
```

I want to join these tables to be something like this.

```
id, places, some_meta
1, "Name1, Name2", some_meta
2, "Name2, Name3", some_meta
```

I'm stuck in the FROM subquery right now.

```
FROM
  table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

That's what I have so far. How do I join `t1.place_ids` with `table3` to get the name of the place? I don't know HIVE really well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lateral view` with `explode` on the array and use the values for `join`.

```
select t1.id,concat_ws(',',collect_list(t3.places)),t2.some_meta
from (select id,places
      from table1
      lateral view explode(place_id) tbl as places
     ) t1
join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
join t3 on t1.places=t3.id
group by t1.id,t2.some_meta
```